# Call to undefined function BaconQrCode\Encoder\iconv()

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel, qr-code

I use QRcode for my laravel project on my localserver and it worked correctly.
But now, as I deploy my project on cpanel, I got this error:

> Call to undefined function BaconQrCode\Encoder\iconv()

I did follow [these intructions](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/enabling-iconv.603743/) and still no luck.

I really don't know what's going on...
I'm testing it with simple QRcode usage:

```
QrCode::generate('Make me into a QrCode!');
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks...

Comment: did you use `iconv` before qrcode generation? Post the line here if you used that function.

Comment: yeah i did. 
Installed:
  ea-php56-php-iconv.x86_64 0:5.6.39-1.1.2.cpanel

Comment: You understood me wrong, Can you post the line that contains the `iconv` function?

Comment: oh sorry for missunderstanding! I didnt use iconv directly, i just use the line that i mentioned above using QrCode and apparantly it's using php extension iconv!!

Comment: The package might not be suitable for using inside Laravel then. Try using another QRCode package with support for Laravel. https://github.com/search?q=laravel+qrcode

Comment: Maybe, but how come it worked on local then?!
by the way i really appreciate you answering me, because no one else is:(

Comment: compare your `phpinfo();` output then. You might catch a difference

Comment: And maybe you forgot to restart your Apache :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
{!! QrCode::generate('Make me into a QrCode!') !!}
```

Comment: @kalantari: Please see this [link](https://github.com/SimpleSoftwareIO/simple-qrcode/issues/16)